# Are the events generated by a split of a collection of infinite independent events $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\{A_n,n\in N\}$ are independent events. Define $C_n := \bigcup_{m=1}^{n}A_m$ and $D_n := \bigcup_{m=n+1}^{\infty}A_m$. How to show $C_n$ and $D_n$ are independent?

I'd like to prove by definition directly. My problem is, the definition of independent events is defined regarding every possible finite subset. So it's hard to apply the definition directly here...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387423/independence-of-sigma-algebras/1387491#1387491

Comment: @d.k.o.Got it! Build $\pi-$systems and then use $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem! Thank you so much!:-)